# Communicating between Angular.js and bottle.py

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, bottle

This should be easy. But there is apparently some problem. So I want to read some data off a bottle server in the following HTML file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pushing data to the server</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='app3.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='friendsController'>
        {{someString}}
        <button ng-click='loadFriends()' > Load Friends </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('friendsController', function($scope, $http){
    //code here
    $scope.someString = 'This is some string';

    $scope.loadFriends = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8000/').success(function(data){
            $scope.someString = 'Yay';
        }).error(function(){
            $scope.someString = 'Some error occured';
        });
    };
});
```

And the bottle server is as follows:

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/')
def hello(): return {"test":"someData"}

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

So everything is really simple! So now I test the program, after pressing the button I always get the error `'Some error occured'`. I tried curling for the server response, and that 'seems' fine ...

```
>curl http://localhost:8000/ -i
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 06:37:50 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Content-Length: 39
Content-Type: application/json

{"test": "someData"}
```

I feel that there is some slight mistake in the code somewhere which I am not able to ascertain. Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

N.B.: I have already tried various types of output in the Python server ...

1. `def hello(): return {"test":"someData"}`
2. `def hello(): return 'someData'`
3. `def hello(): return True`
4. `def hello(): return '{"test":"someData"}'`

None of these seem to have made any difference ...

I always get this error in the javascript console in Chrome if that is any help:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Apparently that means that a datatype problem. So I tried different return statements.

Comment: is your page on same domain and port? check browser console for CORS errors

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I am not really sure what that is. I can directly load that data by pasting it in the browser path. But not from angular.js

Comment: you need to correctly configure CORS in your bottle server, so the client side can receive data. once you did it, it will work.

 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing     
 - https://gist.github.com/richard-flosi/3789163

Comment: @BuriB: Thanks for the suggestions. Ill go through the links...

Comment: one quick fix is to serve the html file from a bottle controller

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. The CORS thing really solved my problem like magic. I would never have figured it out by myself !!